# Show that $M^{\mu\nu}$ describes the angular momentum of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Define

$M^{\mu\nu}$ = $\int d^3x(x^\mu T^{0 \nu}-x^{\nu}T^{0 \mu})$ describes the angular momentum of the system.

I don't want you to solve it but I'm not really sure what kind of criterion it wants me to check to see if it's angular momentum.

It's like it's missing the following outline:

This mathematical object is angular momentum if it satisfies:

(1) $L$ = $r \times p$

(2) It satisfies some conservation law....

I'm not really sure, I made (1) and (2) up to be honest.

Also, does any body want to explain how $d^3x$ corresponds to time?

Comment: What is the formula for $T^{\mu\nu}$? Is $T^{\mu \nu}$ the stress-energy tensor? Figuring that out is where I would start...

Comment: Also: "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum" and "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress–energy_tensor"

Comment: Yes it's the stress-energy tensor, which is symmetric. Also it represents the momentum so I know it follows the conservation of momentum law.

Comment: And so what's the formula for the stress-energy tensor? Why don't you plug that in and see if you get anything that looks like angular momentum (e.g., maybe like $x^\mu v^\nu - x^\nu v^\mu$)...

Comment: Yes, which is really like $x \times p$, by definition of the cross product.

Comment: Okay and by definition $T^{\mu\nu} = CU^{\mu}U^{\nu}$ (this has 16 terms and can be represented by a 4x4 matrix), where C is some constant and U is the 4-velocity which is the proper time derivative of the 4-position vector.